# How do I order rows after using "Fetch First" in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sql-fetch

I have an Oracle SQL query that uses [`FETCH FIRST`](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-fetch/) to find employees with the highest annual salary in a PeopleSoft database.

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.ANNUAL_RT
FROM PS_EMPLOYEES A
ORDER BY A.ANNUAL_RT DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

```
EMPLID   ANNUAL_RT
20218    100000
10300    100000
26992    100000
17864    100000
```

I want to sort my results by EMPLID. However, since I'm using `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES`, adding `EMPLID` to my `ORDER BY` clause limits my results to the 1 employee with the lowest ID number.

```sql
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.ANNUAL_RT
FROM PS_EMPLOYEES A
ORDER BY A.ANNUAL_RT DESC, A.EMPLID ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES;
```

```
EMPLID   ANNUAL_RT
10300    100000
```

How can I sort my results ***without*** affecting which rows are returned by `FETCH FIRST`?

```
EMPLID   ANNUAL_RT
10300    100000
17864    100000
20218    100000
26992    100000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose your query as a *table expression* (a common table expression will also do). This way you can post-process it.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT A.EMPLID, A.ANNUAL_RT
  FROM PS_EMPLOYEES A
  ORDER BY A.ANNUAL_RT DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
) x
order by emplid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RANK()`](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-rank/) or `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `FETCH FIRST`.

```
SELECT EMPLID, ANNUAL_RT
FROM (
  SELECT
    A.EMPLID,
    A.ANNUAL_RT,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.ANNUAL_RT DESC) AS RANK_NO
  FROM PS_EMPLOYEES A
)
WHERE RANK_NO = 1
ORDER BY EMPLID;
```

Results:

```
EMPLID   ANNUAL_RT
10300    100000
17864    100000
20218    100000
26992    100000
```